# MS Visio no lines jumps over lines from hidden layers

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am using multiple layers with connectors to objects. The connectors are part of multiple hidden layers. How can I prevent any visible connector to create a jump line over these hidden lines but still create jump lines over crossing visible lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue.  On another web forum, I found this - I hope it helps! (Copy-paste starts here)

SOLVED >> here is the solution ...

### Pre-Condition:

Layer A - lines that will show no jumps AT ALL, not even to the lines in the
layer itself, so all lines are FLAT and have the "never" selected.

Layer B - lines that already show jumps over their own lines within the
layer (which is OK), AND also show you the line jumps from Layer A (which is
not OK), even though you have selected that/those layers (Layer A) to be
'invisible'.

### Solution:

Do the following in Layer A.

Format > Behavior > Connector > Line Jumps - add - "to neither"

### Conclusion:

Errors that showed up Layer B, remember those random line jumps when there
were no lines there, because you have told Layer A to be invisible? Well now
they are no longer visible, because you have selected the lines within Layer
A "to neither".

Comment: Please edit the answer to include a link to the information source that you refer to.